# Why is nothing displayed under the 'Related' sidebar?

Tags: feature-request

Previously, whenever I asked a question, there used to be a 'Related' tab on the right side. It used to display links to a lot of related posts. Now, I can still see the tab 'Related', but no suggested posts under it. Has there been a recent change on the site regarding this?

Comment: [Known problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350569/the-list-of-related-questions-is-shown-empty) though the SE haven't responded yet.

Comment: It has been fixed now.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Yes, thanks. I can see it.